# Query pages by category

Tags: categories, query-posts

Trying to query pages based on the category they are associated with. I am passing in the cat_ID, but it doesn't seem to be working. Always returns a single post with the title "Hello World" while there is an actual page with real title associated with this category.

```
// The Query
query_posts('cat='.$current);

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    the_title();

endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the default query is only querying for post_type post, you have to explicitly add page to get it to also query for pages:

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => $current,
    'post_type' => array( 'page', 'post' )
);
query_posts( $args );
```